# how to get all the columns in the same height in html and css

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am new to web technologies. I intended to do a project. I want to display all these columns at the same height, but they are not being at same height.
I am getting the output in such a way that the 3 columns are not at same level. I want them to start at same height and may end at different heights. how should I correct it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Notices</title>
</head>
<style>
    div{
        display:inline-block;
    }
    li{
        padding-bottom:10px;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div style="border:1px solid #0a81ab;width:30%;margin-right:20px">
    <h3 style="padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:#0a81ab;color:white; font-size:20px">Latest News</h3>
    <ul type="circle">
        <li>AWS CLOUD LITERACY DAY</li>
        <li>Anblicks Ignite Program for 4/4 B.Tech Students</li>
        <li>21-09-2019 i.e., Saturday is declared as holiday in lieu of 15-09-2019 to all students, faculty and s...</li>
        <li>Spot Admissions 2019:Vacancy Position for B.Tech First Year</li>
        <li>I/IV B.Tech I & II Semesters Academic Calendar for the year 2019-20</li>
        <li>Department of IT is introducing M.Tech in Data Science for A.Y. 2019-20</li>
        <li>AWS CLOUD LITERACY DAY</li>
        <li>Anblicks Ignite Program for 4/4 B.Tech Students</li>
        <li>21-09-2019 i.e., Saturday is declared as holiday in lieu of 15-09-2019 to all students, faculty and s...</li>
        <li>Spot Admissions 2019:Vacancy Position for B.Tech First Year</li>
        <li>I/IV B.Tech I & II Semesters Academic Calendar for the year 2019-20</li>
    </ul>
    <p style="color:grey;float:right;">new archives>></p>
</div>
<div style="border:1px solid #ce1f6a;width:30%;margin-right:20px;">
    <h3 style="padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:#ce1f6a;color:white; font-size:20px">Examinations Notice Board</h3>
    <ul type="circle">
        <li>Exam fee notifications for B.Tech., III,VI & VII-Semesters and MCA V-Semesters Nov-2019</li>
        <li>Results of M.Tech IV-Semester(Project-viva) September-2019</li>
        <li>CBCS B.Tech., V,VI,VII & VIII-Semesters (Subjects) Exam fee notification of Nov/Dec-2019</li>
        <li>Timetable for B.Tech I to IV-Semesters(VR10 & VR14)-Supple- Oct-2019</li>
        <li>Exam fee notification for B.Tech IV & V-Semesters Examinations - Nov-2019</li>
        <li>Exam fee notifications for B.Tech., III,VI & VII-Semesters and MCA V-Semesters Nov-2019</li>
        <li>Results of M.Tech IV-Semester(Project-viva) September-2019</li>
        <li>CBCS B.Tech., V,VI,VII & VIII-Semesters (Subjects) Exam fee notification of Nov/Dec-2019</li>
        <li>Timetable for B.Tech I to IV-Semesters(VR10 & VR14)-Supple- Oct-2019</li>
        
    </ul>
    <p style="color:grey;float:right;">new archives>></p>
</div>
<div style="border:1px solid #54e346;width:30%;">
    <h3 style="padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:#54e346;color:white; font-size:20px">Quick Links</h3>
    <ul type="circle">
        <li>Institution Innovation Council</li>
        <li>Internal Sliding 2019 Notice</li>
        <li>Collaborative Labs</li>
        <li>Intellectual Property Policy</li>
        <li>Choice Based Credit System Guidelines</li>
        <li>Institutional Electives for 3/4 B.Tech Students</li>
        <li>Accredition status</li>
        <li>NIRF</li>
        <li>Faculty Details</li>
        <li>Punishments for malpractice cases in exams</li>
        <li>Academic Calendar</li>
        <li>Governing Body Minutes</li>
        <li>NAAC Self Study Report</li>
        <li>AICTE Feedback (Faculty/Students)</li>
    </ul>
    <p style="color:grey;float:right;">new archives>></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What changes should I make in this to get all three columns at same level (at top)?

Comment: Use ```flex``` instead, that should fix it for you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Notices</title>
</head>
<style>
      .flex-container {
        display: flex;
      }
    
    li{
        padding-bottom:10px;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div class="flex-container">
<div style="border:1px solid #0a81ab;width:30%;margin-right:20px">
    <h3 style="padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:#0a81ab;color:white; font-size:20px">Latest News</h3>
    <ul type="circle">
        <li>AWS CLOUD LITERACY DAY</li>
        <li>Anblicks Ignite Program for 4/4 B.Tech Students</li>
        <li>21-09-2019 i.e., Saturday is declared as holiday in lieu of 15-09-2019 to all students, faculty and s...</li>
        <li>Spot Admissions 2019:Vacancy Position for B.Tech First Year</li>
        <li>I/IV B.Tech I & II Semesters Academic Calendar for the year 2019-20</li>
        <li>Department of IT is introducing M.Tech in Data Science for A.Y. 2019-20</li>
        <li>AWS CLOUD LITERACY DAY</li>
        <li>Anblicks Ignite Program for 4/4 B.Tech Students</li>
        <li>21-09-2019 i.e., Saturday is declared as holiday in lieu of 15-09-2019 to all students, faculty and s...</li>
        <li>Spot Admissions 2019:Vacancy Position for B.Tech First Year</li>
        <li>I/IV B.Tech I & II Semesters Academic Calendar for the year 2019-20</li>
    </ul>
    <p style="color:grey;float:right;">new archives>></p>
</div>
<div style="border:1px solid #ce1f6a;width:30%;margin-right:20px;">
    <h3 style="padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:#ce1f6a;color:white; font-size:20px">Examinations Notice Board</h3>
    <ul type="circle">
        <li>Exam fee notifications for B.Tech., III,VI & VII-Semesters and MCA V-Semesters Nov-2019</li>
        <li>Results of M.Tech IV-Semester(Project-viva) September-2019</li>
        <li>CBCS B.Tech., V,VI,VII & VIII-Semesters (Subjects) Exam fee notification of Nov/Dec-2019</li>
        <li>Timetable for B.Tech I to IV-Semesters(VR10 & VR14)-Supple- Oct-2019</li>
        <li>Exam fee notification for B.Tech IV & V-Semesters Examinations - Nov-2019</li>
        <li>Exam fee notifications for B.Tech., III,VI & VII-Semesters and MCA V-Semesters Nov-2019</li>
        <li>Results of M.Tech IV-Semester(Project-viva) September-2019</li>
        <li>CBCS B.Tech., V,VI,VII & VIII-Semesters (Subjects) Exam fee notification of Nov/Dec-2019</li>
        <li>Timetable for B.Tech I to IV-Semesters(VR10 & VR14)-Supple- Oct-2019</li>
        
    </ul>
    <p style="color:grey;float:right;">new archives>></p>
</div>
<div style="border:1px solid #54e346;width:30%;">
    <h3 style="padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:#54e346;color:white; font-size:20px">Quick Links</h3>
    <ul type="circle">
        <li>Institution Innovation Council</li>
        <li>Internal Sliding 2019 Notice</li>
        <li>Collaborative Labs</li>
        <li>Intellectual Property Policy</li>
        <li>Choice Based Credit System Guidelines</li>
        <li>Institutional Electives for 3/4 B.Tech Students</li>
        <li>Accredition status</li>
        <li>NIRF</li>
        <li>Faculty Details</li>
        <li>Punishments for malpractice cases in exams</li>
        <li>Academic Calendar</li>
        <li>Governing Body Minutes</li>
        <li>NAAC Self Study Report</li>
        <li>AICTE Feedback (Faculty/Students)</li>
    </ul>
    <p style="color:grey;float:right;">new archives>></p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added one css to body. i agree with ddmmcc, but it's more simple.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Notices</title>
</head>
<style>
    body{
          display:flex;
    }
    div{
        display:inline-block;
    }
    li{
        padding-bottom:10px;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div style="border:1px solid #0a81ab;width:30%;margin-right:20px">
    <h3 style="padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:#0a81ab;color:white; font-size:20px">Latest News</h3>
    <ul type="circle">
        <li>AWS CLOUD LITERACY DAY</li>
        <li>Anblicks Ignite Program for 4/4 B.Tech Students</li>
        <li>21-09-2019 i.e., Saturday is declared as holiday in lieu of 15-09-2019 to all students, faculty and s...</li>
        <li>Spot Admissions 2019:Vacancy Position for B.Tech First Year</li>
        <li>I/IV B.Tech I & II Semesters Academic Calendar for the year 2019-20</li>
        <li>Department of IT is introducing M.Tech in Data Science for A.Y. 2019-20</li>
        <li>AWS CLOUD LITERACY DAY</li>
        <li>Anblicks Ignite Program for 4/4 B.Tech Students</li>
        <li>21-09-2019 i.e., Saturday is declared as holiday in lieu of 15-09-2019 to all students, faculty and s...</li>
        <li>Spot Admissions 2019:Vacancy Position for B.Tech First Year</li>
        <li>I/IV B.Tech I & II Semesters Academic Calendar for the year 2019-20</li>
    </ul>
    <p style="color:grey;float:right;">new archives>></p>
</div>
<div style="border:1px solid #ce1f6a;width:30%;margin-right:20px;">
    <h3 style="padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:#ce1f6a;color:white; font-size:20px">Examinations Notice Board</h3>
    <ul type="circle">
        <li>Exam fee notifications for B.Tech., III,VI & VII-Semesters and MCA V-Semesters Nov-2019</li>
        <li>Results of M.Tech IV-Semester(Project-viva) September-2019</li>
        <li>CBCS B.Tech., V,VI,VII & VIII-Semesters (Subjects) Exam fee notification of Nov/Dec-2019</li>
        <li>Timetable for B.Tech I to IV-Semesters(VR10 & VR14)-Supple- Oct-2019</li>
        <li>Exam fee notification for B.Tech IV & V-Semesters Examinations - Nov-2019</li>
        <li>Exam fee notifications for B.Tech., III,VI & VII-Semesters and MCA V-Semesters Nov-2019</li>
        <li>Results of M.Tech IV-Semester(Project-viva) September-2019</li>
        <li>CBCS B.Tech., V,VI,VII & VIII-Semesters (Subjects) Exam fee notification of Nov/Dec-2019</li>
        <li>Timetable for B.Tech I to IV-Semesters(VR10 & VR14)-Supple- Oct-2019</li>
        
    </ul>
    <p style="color:grey;float:right;">new archives>></p>
</div>
<div style="border:1px solid #54e346;width:30%;">
    <h3 style="padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:#54e346;color:white; font-size:20px">Quick Links</h3>
    <ul type="circle">
        <li>Institution Innovation Council</li>
        <li>Internal Sliding 2019 Notice</li>
        <li>Collaborative Labs</li>
        <li>Intellectual Property Policy</li>
        <li>Choice Based Credit System Guidelines</li>
        <li>Institutional Electives for 3/4 B.Tech Students</li>
        <li>Accredition status</li>
        <li>NIRF</li>
        <li>Faculty Details</li>
        <li>Punishments for malpractice cases in exams</li>
        <li>Academic Calendar</li>
        <li>Governing Body Minutes</li>
        <li>NAAC Self Study Report</li>
        <li>AICTE Feedback (Faculty/Students)</li>
    </ul>
    <p style="color:grey;float:right;">new archives>></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```